# Run a server and client in a makefile

Tags: bash, make, testing, file-server, parallelism

I'm coding a socket file server in C++, and I can't figure out how to put proper unit testing into my makefile. My problem is as follows:

The server, when started, spits out its port number to stdout. It then listens, ad infinitum. The client process (my test suite) needs to read the server's output, and then start up in its own, parallel process.

How can I write a script which will both 1. run the two programs in parallel, 2. allow me to get output from one to the other properly, 3. allow me to store the output in a nice format for later viewing.

Comment: Why a makefile? You could use a makefile, but it seems inappropriate.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27254227/7552

Comment: Well, a makefile is just for testing purposes, but the question is equivalently a bash question. We're just running bash commands inside a makefile, so far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write a script which will both 1. run the two programs in parallel, 2. allow me to get output from one to the other properly, 3. allow me to store the output in a nice format for later viewing.

Personally, I'd write the test harness in C++ too, but either way, if you want to do this kind of multiple process client server test you need to `fork()`.

In bash that's achieved with `&`, so the equivalent of

```c
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) // error handling
else if (!pid) {
    // Start server, plus some code for evaluating the exchange.
} else {
    // Wait a second or two, then start client.
    // Plus some code to feed server and evaluate exchange.
}
```

in shell could be something like:

```
(
    output=$(start_server)
    # evaluate output
) &
sleep 2
start_client < input.txt
```

Depending on the nature of the beast, the shell method could be awkward or impossible to do as well as the C++ method.  Also, using the same language means you can test by instantiating your classes and such rather than the kit and kaboodle as a whole.  This makes it easier to isolate problems, and  you can include genuine [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).